# Matplotlib Truetype font encoding

Tags: pdf, encoding, matplotlib, fonts, truetype

I use the following code to generate PDF/PS figures with Truetype fonts in Matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('pdf',fonttype = 42)
plt.rc('ps',fonttype = 42)
```

This generates an output PDF/EPS with the fonts encodes as "Identity-H". I was wondering if it is possible to set the encoding to be "built-in". (For pdfs generated from, say, MATLAB, the font encoding is usually "built-in", as shown by Adobe Reader in Windows.)

Comment: The list of "built-in" encodings is small, and so is the set of characters supported by it. I doubt there is an option to manually set the encoding - it depends on what text you have. "Identity-H" basically means a 1-to-1 mapping of an encoding to the font used, no further actions needed. It should be harmless; can you explain why you want this?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am trying to use EPS figures for a poster I am making in Powerpoint. Identity-H encoded EPS figures are failing in the import, while Type-3 font figures (exported from Matplotlib) are importing fine as their encoding seems to be of type "custom". But, Type-3 font figures are not allowed in a lot of publications, and so, I want to find a way to achieve both Truetype and non-Identity-H encoding in order to avoid having to maintain many different versions of files.